# Issue while installing angular cli on stable node version

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v9

Facing an issue while Installing Angular CLI.

Tried all the possible workaround like clearing cache, uninstalling, and reinstalling Node. Manually clearing folder of npm-cache in Appdata.

The attached screenshot is the error I am facing when I hit **npm install -g @angular/cli --verbose**

Version I am using

- NODE - v12.18.3
- NPM - 6.14.6

**Error Facing**
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...wzttNqx4uELH8YM5zUFTi'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First connect to a very good internet connection like wifi or something

**clear the npm cache** & then try **installing angular** again.